# Client not connecting when used on a different computer to the host

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to write a host/client style system that uses WCF and its wsHttpBinding to get data from another machine running the host software and it is working absolutely fine when I use it on the same machine to the host but when the client is on a different machine it does not work and throws an EndpointNotFoundException:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no
 endpoint listening at http://192.168.1.64/GettingStarted/CalculatorService that
 could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP
action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebExc
eption: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketExc
eption: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
 respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connect
ed host has failed to respond 192.168.1.64:80
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddre
ss socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Sock
et s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state,
IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStre
am()
```

I thought I had done it properly because I am using the IP address of the host in the address instead of localhost but it is not working and I don't know why. Here is my App.config file for the service library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.64/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" />
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.64/host" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And here is the App.config file for the client console (there is nothing in the App.config for the host console:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
              <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
                <security mode="None"></security>
              </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.64/GettingStarted/CalculatorService"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And the code for the client console:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client proxy = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
Console.WriteLine(proxy.InnerChannel.RemoteAddress);
Console.WriteLine(proxy.SayHello("Henry"));
Console.WriteLine(proxy.OsDetails());            
Console.ReadKey(true);
proxy.Close();
```

What am I doing wrong/not doing so that it does not connect when the client is on another machine? Is it something to do with security? This is the part that I always get stuck on whenever trying to make WCF services so I would greatly appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: "(there is nothing in the App.config for the host console" - libraries don't use the config file that is included in the library project - they use the config file of the application that is using the library.  Try moving the `<system.serviceModel>` settings from the library App.config to the console `App.config`.

Comment: I have done that but it gives me an error in the host: 
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. If your service is being h
osted in IIS you can fix the problem by setting 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' to true or specifying 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/baseAdd
ressPrefixFilters'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your firewall or router is blocking the communication. Try turning off the firewall.